# Adding and position an icon to a figure's caption

Tags: graphics, pdftex, captions

so my problem is this: I need to add an icon to a figure's caption in order to provide extra visual information (in this case to show that there is a PDF available for a given picture) in a specific position, to the right. So I have this code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height = 5.0cm]{hello.png}
\caption{This is my way to say hello!}
\label{fig:0101}
\end{figure}
```

which renders:

[image: hello]

What I would like to do is add something that would render like this:

[image: hello with icon]

I also have some captions with more than 1 line so I need to align the icon vertically with the caption's text.

I already have the book written (500+ pages, it's a new edition with this new icon feature) so I don't want to change all figure environments.

Please help! Many thanks.

Comment: Should the icon also show up in the TOC?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to override `\caption{...}` to load a tikz set that puts the caption in one node and a second image in the other node next to it.

Here is an initial working example using the standard caption (I'm using the QR package to generate QR code for the hyperlink for the image, you can can use your PDF icon or anything else.)

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Generate quick response code for hyperlink.
\usepackage{qrcode}
\newcommand{\tinyqr}[1]{
    \qrcode[hyperlink,level=L,height=0.75cm]{#1}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ctan_lion_600.png}
    \tinyqr{https://ctan.org/lion/files}
    \caption{CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The generates
[image]

---

Then I created a tikz layout to get the format I wanted.  This is where you can fuss around with the layout parameters you like such as spacing.  But this is not using the figure or caption mechanisms so its just for tuning.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Generate quick response code for hyperlink.
\usepackage{qrcode}
\newcommand{\tinyqr}[1]{
    \qrcode[hyperlink,level=L,height=0.75cm]{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
    \node[anchor=south] (fig) at (0,0) {
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ctan_lion_600.png}
    };

    \node[anchor=right,below =of fig,text width=2in] (cap) {
        \textbf{Figure 1} CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.};

    \node[left =of cap] (qr) {\tinyqr{https://ctan.org/lion/files}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This created
[image]

---

Finally I created my own caption command and copied the relevant tikz code in and replaced the caption text with `\caption` (I am amazed it worked).

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Generate quick response code for hyperlink.
\usepackage{qrcode}
\newcommand{\tinyqr}[1]{
    \qrcode[hyperlink,level=L,height=0.75cm]{#1}
}

\newcommand{\sidecaption}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
        \node[text width=2in] (caption) {
            \caption{#1}
        };
        % change left to right if desired
        \node[anchor=bottom,left =of caption] (image) {#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ctan_lion_600.png}
    \sidecaption{
        CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby. % your caption
    }{ 
        \tinyqr{https://ctan.org/lion/files} % your side image
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It generated
[image]
So it wasn't perfect.  Two outstanding problems I don't know how to fix.

- the alignment of the attached QR code/icon.
- I had to set a text width for the caption node, I made it fixed at 2in but in principle you might want that as a parameter for wider/smaller captions such as in any subfigures.  In a perfect world it would be automatic but that is beyond my skill set.

Comment: that was a cut-paste error, sorry, fixed just now.

Comment: Please see my answer re. the outstanding problems. I expect these answers are too late for the OP who asked the question. (Hopefully the book is published by now!) I wonder if this would be better as a separate question, perhaps linked to this one. Not at all sure, though.

Comment: no doubt the OP has moved on. I had my crude solution and was looking for better when I found it this but no answer.  So I shared my feeble answer for anyone else looking.  Glad for the improvements @cfr (and tiger!)

Comment: The tiger is from the `pstricks` documentation. Not as friendly-looking as CTAN's lion, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of [Algeboy's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699217/), which addresses some of the remaining issues it identifies.

If you want to use Ti*k*Z (which isn't really necessary here), you can use anchors to position the second node relative to the first. However, you also need to change the format of captions temporarily, because LaTeX inserts a skip between the contents of the figure and the caption. The following uses the `caption` package to eliminate this space when `\sidecaption` is used.

I've also made the width adjustable. This could probably be calculated automatically, if I knew how you wanted it to be determined. You need to be careful to avoid introducing spurious spaces when defining commands. This is less of an issue when using Ti*k*Z, but it may affect `\sidecaption`, for example.

As a debugging tip: if nodes don't align as you expect, add `draw` to see if any of them are larger or smaller than they appear. In the case of your original code, you'd have seen the extra space at the top of `caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{caption}

% Generate quick response code for hyperlink.
\usepackage{qrcode}
\newcommand{\tinyqr}[1]{%
  \qrcode[hyperlink,level=L,height=0.75cm]{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\sidecaption}{ O {2in} m m }{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
    \node[text width=#1] (caption) {%
      \captionsetup{skip=0pt}%
      \caption{#2}%
    };
    % change left to right and west to east if desired
    \node[anchor=center,left=of caption.west] (image) {#3};
  \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}
  \sidecaption{%
    Not the CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.% your caption
  }{%
    \tinyqr{https://ctan.org/lion/files}% your side image
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned QR code and caption beneath a tiger which isn't the CTAN lion]